# csv parsing into arrays in d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am having trouble parsing my csv file into an empty array.  It seems that I can parse the file but I can't seem to fill the array.

Here is an abridged view my csv file (157 rows - showing 9 here):

`"",percentage
"1",0.275862068965517
"2",0.137931034482759
"3",0.133333333333333
"4",0.4
"5",0.633333333333333
"6",0.766666666666667
"7",0.379310344827586
"8",0.724137931034483
"9",0.933333333333333`

Here is my code in d3:

```
var values = [];

d3.csv("wlythree.csv", function(data) {
  values = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["percentage"] ]; });
});

console.log(values)
```

It prints out in the console an empty array.  I put in the console.log just to check my code - it's not needed besides for that purpose.   All I need is the percentage column in the array and the rest of my code works perfectly.  I cannot seem to figure out and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did my reply to your comment explain the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
d3.csv("wlythree.csv", function(data) {
    var values = [];
    values = data.map(function(d) { return d.percentage; });

    console.log(values)
});
```

It yields:

```
["0.275862068965517", "0.137931034482759", ...]
```

EDIT: placed declaration of `values` inside the callback since the csv loading is asynchronous and that better reflects the script flow.

Comment: thanks for the response!  not exactly what i'm looking for though.  I guess to be explain it I want the global variable values to be filled with those values.

Comment: so if you put console.log(values) outside the function it should be filled with percentage data

Comment: You have to remember that the csv loading is **asynchronous**. You either need to do all that involves variable `values` inside this calback function or inside another function that you call from it. If you use `values` outside of the callback(s), there is no guarantee it would have been set prior to your use of it. Makes sense? You can search here at SO for d3.csv and get more information. I am going to edit my response and place the declaration of `values` inside the call because that better reflects what is going on.